# Trying to set property in parent viewcontroller, but it ends up being Null

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I'm in a view controller that was pushed onto the stack by by a navigation controller.

I have this code that runs when the back button is pressed:

```
- (void)didMoveToParentViewController:(UIViewController *)parent {
    if (![parent isEqual:self.parentViewController]) {            
        //NSLog(@"Back pressed");
        MyCustomViewController *vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"TableVC"];
        vc.index = [_itemChooser selectedRowInComponent:0];
    }    
}
```

I'm trying to set index to the same index of what I chose in the picker view. If I NSLog the value here, it is correct, but if I NSLog the value in viewWillAppear in the parent, it is 0.
(It prints as Null if I'm using an object rather than an NSUInteger)

Pushed it on like this:

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:pickervc animated:YES];
```

Comment: why are you pushing parentviewcontroller instead of popover? and as per your code i think your IF(![parent isEqual:self.parentviewcontroller]]) is wrong remove ! from condition

Comment: I pushed the child onto the stack from inside the parent.

Comment: I know the ! is strange, but when I don't do the check, it happens both when I push and pop.

Comment: can you explain in what you want to do ? with your code? so it is easy to help you...

Comment: I thought it was pretty clear, I want to set the property 'index' in the view controller I was in before I entered the other view controller. It's meant to hold the index of the selected item from a picker view.

Comment: yes you have to set Property in childviewcontroller and synthesize that sharing instance

Comment: You mean assign it in the childviewcontroller? Like I'm already doing?

And should I be synthesizing it in the parent or the child? (And why would synthesizing and using the getter from that be better than just directly assigning?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem by defining a view controller property in the child class, and assigning self to it before pushing. I was then able to set/access properties from the parent in the child no problem.